# Retrieve combinations from different rows as inputs SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to SQL and I am kind of stuck at an issue. I have a table with following structure... The table format is something that I cannot change. I have tried INNER joins and cross join but that did not help me much.

I have to retrieve all the records which depends on my input for example if my input will be Chicago, Sedan and chilly.

I should retrieve only combination of Chicago or Sedan or Chilly or Chicago and Sedan or Chicago and chilly and so on... for example in the following table ID 4 should not be retrieved as it is combination of new york and chilly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ID  TYPE    CODE
1   CITY    Chicago
1   CAR     SEDAN
1   WEATHER CHILLY
2   WEATHER CHILLY
2   CAR     SEDAN
3   CITY    Chicago
4   CITY    New York
4   CAR SEDAN
```

[image: Table Format]

Comment: What if for ID 1 you have some other value other than this combination, say "LA". Do you want to display that as well?

Comment: and for `3` you have only `Chicago` but it is not combined with anything. Do you need it too?

Comment: yes Utsav so City can be Chicago and LA for same ID that needs to be retrieved and if it is only Chicago or Sedan or Chilly should be retrieved as well. so the ID should be one or many of the combination but any other combination apart from Input for example LA and Chilly for a record should not be retrieved... thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

Sai,

You can give this a try to see if this is what you are after.

I did add one more line to your original example table just to help illustrate how this SQL would render.

```html
ID  TYPE    CODE
1   CITY    Chicago
1   CITY    Dallas
1   CAR     SEDAN
1   WEATHER CHILLY
2   WEATHER CHILLY
2   CAR     SEDAN
3   CITY    Chicago
4   CITY    New York
4   CAR SEDAN
```

Using this SQL will render your table output is a more manageable format.

```
    SELECT * FROM 
((select id, type, code from   TABLE1 t1)
 pivot (listagg(code,',') within group (order by type) 
        for type in('CITY' as CITY,'CAR' as CAR, 'WEATHER' as WEATHER)))
 order by id
```

This will turn the table format above to the following formatted record set.

```html
ID CITY             CAR     WEATHER
1  Chicago,Dallas   SEDAN   CHILLY
2  (null)           SEDAN   CHILLY
3  Chicago          (null)  (null)
4  New York         SEDAN   (null)
```

Of course, if you wish to place quotes around each item in the output you could do this.

```
    SELECT * FROM 
((select id, type, code from   TABLE1 t1)
 pivot (listagg(''''||code||'''',',') within group (order by type) 
        for type in('CITY' as CITY,'CAR' as CAR, 'WEATHER' as WEATHER)))
 order by id
```

This would then render as

```html
ID    CITY                CAR      WEATHER
1     'Chicago','Dallas'  'SEDAN'  'CHILLY'
2     (null)              'SEDAN'  'CHILLY'
3     'Chicago'           (null)   (null)
4     'New York'          'SEDAN'  (null)
```

Is this more to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when code in ('Chicago', 'Sedan', 'chilly') then 1 else 0 end) = count(*);
```

Perhaps you intend:

```
having sum(case when type = 'City' and code <> 'Chicago' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when type = 'Car' and code <> 'Sedan' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when type = 'Weather' and code <> 'Chilly' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Hello Gordon... Thank you for your response but unfortunately that query retrieves only when type is one of them but doesnt retrieve the combination... for example chicago and Sedan

Comment: Gordon the last query did not give expected results. The initial query works apart from the multiple combinations as the values in the SQLFiddle.

Comment: Hello Gordon query works fine apart from situation where there is more than one entry for the type... for example city as chicago and new york fails to retrieve. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Slight extension of Gordon's query

**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b844db/13**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1
WHERE t1.ID IN 
(SELECT ID
FROM TABLE1 t2
GROUP BY ID
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN CODE IN ('Chicago','SEDAN','CHILLY')
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    = COUNT(*)
)
```

Comment: Hello Utsav... I have updated SQL fiddle and if you see message ID 3 I have cities as Chicago and New York that should come in the list but that is missing in the result with the query.